# Checkboxes not visible within dialog in jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Tried mimicking the example from the [jQueryUI website](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/), however the actual checkboxes are not visible. Can someone give me any advice on this.

Desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

Actual Output

[image: Actual Output]

Source code from the website I mimicked to get my output:

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Hotel Ratings: </legend>
    <label for="checkbox-1">2 Star</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
    <label for="checkbox-2">3 Star</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
    <label for="checkbox-3">4 Star</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3">
    <label for="checkbox-4">5 Star</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4">
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It looks like you're missing the jQueryUI CSS that would make those appear. Looking at the site reference, there is a gray background around the checkboxes, and without that, a white checkbox on a white background will appear to be missing (just like white text on a white background appears to be blank). I bet if you click around, you can toggle the checkboxes, or click and drag to highlight areas of the page will likely expose their existence.